# Back end python query retrieving mysql id for user

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, server-side

I'm trying to understand **Python Web Development**, particularly the part with using sessions and I can't seem to understand what this line of code means.  Basically, I'm trying to retrieve the `id` of the form of a user login and the only information of the user is the email they entered.  what does that zero mean at `id[0]['id']`??

I was going to have hidden labels and use names in my forms, so I can use `retrieve.form['id']` along with other columns.  Is there anything wrong with this approach?

```
get_id = "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE email = '{}'".format(session['email'])
id = mysql.query_from_databbase(get_id)
session['id'] = id[0]['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are querying a **list** of users_id whose `email = session['email']`...so the output of this query obviously will be a list of objects(or list of ids object in your case).

So, by `id[0]` you are setting `session['id']` to the first one of id list

Comment: thanks! i suppose seesion acts like a dictionary not like a list?

Comment: @YosepKim .. Please, review Flask's [doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.session) for me details.

Comment: @YosepKim...if this didn't solve your issue then edit your question with more details otherwise accept it or post an answer of your findings